# Verb for abolishing a position

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that *abolish* may be used for  practices (ex. to abolish slavery), and with institutions (ex. to abolish The Department of Education). What is the correct way to speak about abolishing a *position*? Suppose for example that the Parliament decides to put an end to the *position* of Secretary of State, absorbing its duties in that of the President.

Comment: There is **absolutely nothing wrong** with ["abolish the office of"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="abolish+the+office+of").

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [Eliminate](https://www.google.com/search?q=eliminate+position) would be a good choice of words.

https://www.salon.com/2018/03/23/trump-considers-eliminating-chief-of-staff-position-entirely-preferring-to-go-it-alone_partner/

> Trump considers eliminating Chief of Staff position entirely, preferring to go it alone

And more Trump (coincidentally), from UK newspaper:

https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jul/21/donald-trump-administration-us-government-jobs-unfilled

> The argument is not very persuasive, said Stier, because Trump is not **eliminating** the positions, he is just not filling them – and the positions in question, a mere fraction of total government employees, still require federal officials to fill them on an acting basis.